# Get the median from a 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, median

I'm all new to programming and I have started to learn Java 2 months ago.
I have been assigned to do a small program, and a part of this program I have to get the median from a 2D array. The 2D array consists 3 subjects and a (N) number of students. I have to get the median for each subject, but I can not really understand how I'm going to sort the numbers from each subject.

Any help, tips or suggestion from were I should start is really appreciated.

Comment: Given the layout, you can't really. You need to transpose the 2D array so you have 3 arrays each containing all the marks for a subject - you can then sort the arrays and get the medians.

Comment: You can sort the array using overloaded function of Arrays class.

Answer (score -1):

Considering **arr** is your 2D array containing double values. Use the following code

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator<double[]>() {
    public int compare(double a, double b) {
        return Double.compare(a[0], b[0]);
    }
});
```

Here **Arrays** and **comparator** are both available under **java.util** package.
If you are using java 8, this can be done in a single line.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> Double.compare(a[0], b[0]));
```

Comment: Your first code snippet has at least two compile errors.  But worse than that, you haven't explained what your code is doing, or why you think it's the answer to the question.  I downvoted, not for the errors, but for the lack of explanation.

Answer (score -1):

you can user [java.util.arrays.sort()](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/) method.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int N=10; // number of students
    double[][] array = new double[3][N];

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)       
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
            array[i][j]= // students scores

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        double[] temp = new double[N];
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
            temp[j]=array[i][j];     // create an array for each subject

            Arrays.sort(temp);     // sort each array
            double median;
            if (temp.length % 2 == 0)   // find median for each case
                median = ((double)temp[temp.length/2] + (double)temp[temp.length/2 - 1])/2;
            else
            median = (double) temp[temp.length/2];
            System.out.println("Median of Subject " +(i+1)+" = " + median);
        }
    }
}
```

you can change data types as you want ...

Comment: Answers that only contain code aren't really what Stack Overflow is about.  I regularly downvote them.  Your answer would be so much better if it contained some kind of explanation of what your code is doing, and why you think it's the right answer to the original question.